# Early parallel computing with human exchanging messages: is this story true?

Tags: computer-science, kolmogorov

As a student in applied maths, I can remember being told that in the 1940s there were early attempts of parallel computing not using any machine but only human calculation power.

I believe the story ran that students were sitting in a classroom and exchanging piece of papers between neighbours. I also believe I was told it was led by Kolmogorov. I have no idea whether this has any true basis and couldn't find a lead on the web.

Comment: This was the usual way computation projects like the ones described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Tables_Project were 
 run .  http://www.philsoc.org/2001Spring/2132transcript.html says the technique was used by de Prony ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaspard_de_Prony#Mechanizing_calculation ) this way.

Comment: Thanks @kimchilover, I've read this but it is not exactly what I'm asking about. Here, human computers are employed to achieve a large number of separate calculations, after work has been divided and reduced to simple arithmetic. However, the story I heard was about actual *parallel* computing, where messages need to be exchanged between computing clerks in order to continue calculation.

Comment: Such a classroom exercise can be done to illustrate the "message-passing algorithm", in particular. I don't have any idea who first might have done this with people emulating nodes. :)